# How to read an immutable record which is inside immutable list?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I could read the immutable list and immutable record independently. But I have an immutable record which is nested inside immutable list which I am not able to read.

Immutable List:

```
let listObj = Immutable.List([{a:'0', b:'1'}, {c:'2', d:'3'}])
console.log('listObj', listObj._tail.array[0]); // {a:'0', b:'1'}
```

Immutable Record:

```
const Person = Immutable.Record({
  name: null
}, 'Person')

let me = Person({ name: 'Steve' })
me.toString() // "Person { "name": "My Name" }"
let myName = me.get('name')
console.log('myName', myName) // "Steve"
```

Immutable Record inside Immutable List:

```
    let x = Immutable.List([Immutable.Record({
        name: 'Steve'
    })])

    console.log('x', x) // undefined
```

Can you please give some pointers, if any, to understand how to read an immutable record which is nested inside an immutable list?

Thanks!

Comment: `console.log('x', x) // undefined`? That’s hard to believe. `x` is defined directly above, so it *cannot* be undefined; and `x.get(0)` should gitve you that record. – Could you try to produce a full [mcve] using [snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try actually running your code:

```js
let x = Immutable.List([Immutable.Record({
  name: 'Steve'
})])

console.log('x', x) // Spoiler alert: NOT undefined
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.js"></script>
```

You'll find that it outputs

```
x List [ function Record(values) {
  ...
} ]
```

Notice how the thing in the list is a `function`? That's because it's a [`Record.Factory`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record.Factory), not actually a `Record` itself. You need to use it like you do in your second example where you create a `Record.Factory` and then use to create a `Record`:

```js
const Person = Immutable.Record({
  name: null
}, 'Person')

let me = Person({
  name: 'Steve'
})

let x = Immutable.List([me])

console.log(x) // [{"name": "Steve"}]
console.log(x.get(0)) // {"name": "Steve"}
console.log(x.getIn([0, 'name'])) // "Steve"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.js"></script>
```